# Prove that $f:X\to S^1$ is null-homotopic iff homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(X,x)\to\pi_1(S^1,f(x))$ is trivial for some $x$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be connected and locally path connected space. Prove that:

$f:X\to S^1$ is null-homotopic iff homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(X,x)\to\pi_1(S^1,f(x))$ is trivial for some $x$.

I do not have any idea how to prove it.

Comment: Have you seen covering spaces and the lifting lemma ?

Comment: @Max, I did although I do not have much experience in that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you've seen covering spaces and the lifting lemma but don't have much experience.

To read this answer, first remember what a [covering space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) is.

Then remember the lifting lemma (I don't know whether it's its actual name), which strongly relates covering spaces, the fundamental group and the possibility of lifting maps up a covering map: [the lifting property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Lifting_properties).  It says the following thing : if you have a space $S$ (here that's $S^1$), a covering $p:E\to S$ (here $E=\mathbb{R}$ and $p:t\mapsto e^{it}$ will do the trick) and a nice enough space $X$ (nice enough means connected and locally path connected-  which are precisely your hypotheses), a point $x_0\in X$, a map $f:X\to S$ and finally a point $e_0\in E$ such that $p(e_0)= f(x_0)$, then you can lift this map up $p$ and send $x_0$ to $e_0$ if and only if $f_\star(\pi_1(X,x_0)) \subset p_\star(\pi_1(E,e_0))$.

Now if $f_\star$ is trivial, then clearly in our situation the inclusion is satisfied, and so we may lift $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$; that is get $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$ with $p\circ g = f$. But then $g$ is null-homotopic, because $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, so $f$ is null-homotopic as well.

Conversely, if $f$ is null-homotopic, consider $H:X\times [0,1]\to S^1$ a homotopy between $f$ and a constant map. Consider then $i:X \to X\times [0,1]$ defined by $i(x) = (x,0)$. Then $i$ is a deformation retraction and so induces an isomorphism on fundamental groups, hence $H_\star (\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,0)) = H_\star(i_\star(\pi_1(X,x_0))) = (H\circ i)_\star(\pi_1(X,x_0)) = f_\star(\pi_1(X,x_0))$.

This shows that if $H_\star$ is trivial, then so is $f_\star$. However if we do the same reasoning with $j:X\to X\times [0,1]$ defined by $j(x) = (x,1)$, we get $H_\star(\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,1)))= 1$ (the trivial group).

Finally we show that $H_\star(\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,1)))$ and $H_\star (\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,0))$ are "sort of conjugate". Indeed let $\gamma: [0,1]\to X\times [0,1]$ be a path from $(x_0,0)$ to $(x_0,1)$ (e.g. $\gamma(t) = (x_0,t)$). Then $\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,1)) = [\gamma^{-1}]\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,0))[\gamma]$ and so $H_\star(\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,1)))= H_\star([\gamma^{-1}]\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,0))[\gamma]) = [H\circ\gamma^{-1}] H_\star(\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,0)))[H\circ\gamma]$.

This seems very obscure, but then we get that $H_\star(\pi_1(X\times [0,1], (x_0,0)))$ is the trivial group, and so $f_\star(\pi_1(X,x_0))$ as well, and so $f_\star$ is trivial.

(This should be easier to deal with with the notion of a fundamental groupoid instead of the notion of fundamental group: note that the "big problem" for this second part is to manage to deal with the change of basepoints, because *a priori* the homotopy between $f$ and the constant map does not preserve any base point. I've hinted at this when I said "sort of conjugate". Of course the intuitive idea is the one in Simonsays's answer : since you can contract the image to a single point, you can contract any loop. I think there must be an easier proof than the one I gave here but I'm not sure)

Answer (score 1):

First two helpful and  important remarks (that you might already know)

- $\pi(\mathbb{S}^1,x)\cong \mathbb{Z}$
- if $X$ is locally path connected and connected, then $X$ is path-connected

clearly if $f:X \rightarrow S^1$ is nullhomotopic, i.e. you can contract the image to a point, then the induced map $f_*$ is zero, since you can in particular contract all loops to a point. For the converse, we assume that $f_*$ equals zero for all closed loops $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow X$.  Note that if we have based spaces $(X,x_0),(Y,y_0)$, then we have that $f(x_0)=y_0$ preserving base points. Now, we choose any point $y=f(x) \in im(f) $. Define $\gamma_x \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$ as a loop connecting $x$ and $x_0$. Then apply $f_*$ to get a loop $ \in \pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1,y_0)$that connects $f(x)=y$ and $f(x_0)=y_0$. By assumption, this loop is contractable, i.e. nullhomotopic. This can be done for any $y$. We define the homotopy $H:X\times I \rightarrow S^1$ as $H(x,t)=f\circ\gamma_x(t)$, so $H(x,0)=f(\gamma_x(0))=f(x) \forall x \in X$,  and $H(x,1)=f(\gamma_x(1))=f(x_0)=y_0$.

Comment: I think in the first direction you need to be more careful: you need to show that you can contract all loops to a point by preserving a fixed base point, not simply contract all loops to a point

Comment: ok yes you are right, my bad.